# Error Installing jupyter kernel for Python 2

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have jupyter notebook installed on Mac with Python 3 Kernel. I tried to install a Kernel for Python 2 using command: `python2 -m pip install ipykernel`, but got the following error:

```
Collecting ipykernel
  Using cached ipykernel-4.6.1-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-client (from ipykernel)
  Using cached jupyter_client-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tornado>=4.0 (from ipykernel)
  Using cached tornado-4.5.1.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, map
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
    monkey.patch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/setuptools/monkey.py", line 48, in patch_all
    distutils.core.Command = setuptools.Command
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Command'
```

Could anyone tell me where the problem is and how to install the kernel for python 2?

Comment: What distribution of python are you using? Anaconda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are running Anaconda I think that entering the following commands into your terminal may work

1) Use create a Python 2.7 conda env

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7
```

2) Activate your new env from the terminal.

```
source activate python2
```

3) Install ipykernel into the python2 env

```
pip install ipykernel
```

4) Install the python2 kernel into ipython

```
ipython kernel install --name python2
```

If you are not running Anaconda try this tutorial; [Create isolated Jupyter ipython kernels with pyenv and virtualenv](http://www.alfredo.motta.name/create-isolated-jupyter-ipython-kernels-with-pyenv-and-virtualenv/)

Please comment below if you are still having issues.

Comment: I am not running Anaconda. When I enter source activate python2, I got: No such file in directory.

Comment: @TianPark I just edited my answer try the instructions at the link that I posted, Let me know if you are still having difficulty.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your timely reply. I am still having difficulty. I followed the instructions outlined in the blog, and added both eval "$(pyenv init -)" and eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)" to my .bashrc file. Everything worked fine except for the command: activate testdir (the virtual env I created). I got the error message: Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.

Comment: @TianPark have you tried using the Anaconda distribution of python? Her are the instructions for [installation on mac osx](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/mac-os) Try installing that and then try the updated first part of my answer.

Comment: Hi James, I installed Anaconda and it worked! Thank you!